# Rotate a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, transaction, alter-table

## Problem description

I need to rotate (with DROP and CREATE) a table which is heavily used by other clients.

At present, I have a program which replaces (DROP + CREATE) this table.

Sometimes, just after the table is replaced, I get "ERROR:  could not open relation with OID xyz" from concurrent clients accessing the table.

One could say this behaviour breaks transaction isolation... Does it?

I understand this is caused by system catalogs being cached by postgres backend (which is normally a good thing). Am I right on it?

Is there any way to force a backend to "forget" table OIDs ([DISCARD](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-discard.html) does not help)?

I know it will help if I switch to "DELETE and INSERT" pattern instead of "DROP and CREATE" pattern. But this is some legacy program and we do not want to change it unless absolutely needed.

I will be grateful for any suggestions how to get rid of this problem.

The goal is to rotate the table transparently for other clients.

## The test case

Here is the minimal test case that I reduced the problem to:

A. This is the client (multiple clients will run this SELECT in parallel). We will use [pgbench](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/pgbench.html) for stressing the database.

```
$ echo "SELECT num FROM x;" > pgbench.minimal.sql
```

B. This is the "rotator".

```
$ cat > rotate.x.sql <<EOF
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE x;
CREATE TABLE x ( num integer );
COMMIT;
EOF
```

C. create empty database and table x.

```
$ createdb dev
$ psql dev -c "CREATE TABLE x ( num integer )"
```

D. Start 30 clients.

```
$ pgbench -c 30 dev -T 60 -n -f pgbench.minimal.sql
```

E. (in other terminal) Run the "rotator".

```
$ psql dev -f rotate.x.sql
```

F. observe what happens to the clients (just after the "rotator" COMMITs).

```
Client 4 aborted in state 1: ERROR:  could not open relation with OID 170429513
LINE 1: SELECT num FROM x;
                        ^
Client 0 aborted in state 1: ERROR:  could not open relation with OID 170429513
LINE 1: SELECT num FROM x;
                        ^
```

(...and so on - every client fails)

## Comments and ideas

What's interesting - even if the clients work in "new connection for each transaction" mode (add "-C" option to pgbench), same error occurs. Not always, and not for every client, but it does.

I asked this question some time ago on mailing list: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2012-04/msg00431.php - this SO post is just a copy.

For more audience: Same thing applies to rotating a partition. So it might be interesting for all people who use partitioning.

This is all on PostgreSQL 9.0, Linux.

## Solution

(thanks to Chris Travers)

```
filip@srv:~$ cat rotate.x.sql
BEGIN;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS xold;
ALTER TABLE x RENAME TO xold;
CREATE TABLE x ( num integer );
COMMIT;
```

Comment: please do not expect people to go read a thread on a mailing list to get the details... all the details should be here. Linking is fine.

Comment: Why use drop & create? A simple TRUNCATE has the same effect.

Comment: xeno, I heard that content duplication is a Bad Thing (tm) ;-)

Comment: a_horse, two reasons (1) TRUNCATE is not mvcc safe, (2) it's a "legacy app", ie. expensive to change

Comment: People, I have improved the question, so I would be thankful if you review it once more and could you please remove the mod-downs. Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error on Postgres 9.4. Seems like this is no longer an issue.

Comment: I managed to reproduce it on 9.1.22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about ALTER TABLE RENAME followed by CREATE TABLE?

Comment: what about relations (foreign keys from and to the table), how are they handled in this case ?

Comment: not only keys, also e.g views that select from this table will deny dropping the old table, because they depend on it

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I have found [here](https://gist.github.com/valyala/ae3cbfa4104f1a022a2af9b8656b1131):

This is the most optimized way:

```
CREATE TABLE parent ... ;
CREATE TABLE child_1() INHERITS (parent);
CREATE TABLE child_2() INHERITS (parent);
```

`INSERT` commands are done always into `child_1`.

`SELECT` commands are done on `parent`.

On your priod of choice, run the follwing sql for rotating `child_1` with `child_2`:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE child_2;
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE child_1 RENAME TO child_tmp;
ALTER TABLE child_2 RENAME TO child_1;
ALTER TABLE child_tmp RENAME TO child_2;
COMMIT;
```

This is much faster comparing to

```
DELETE FROM parent WHERE time < now() - interval 'given period'
```

This also avoids table fragmentation, so SELECT queries work faster on the table.